# set variable that only exists application wise per request in WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am using Basic Auth with SSL to secure my API using ASP.NET WebAPI.  I do not want to use cookies or session variables but I need to have some credentials available and accessible  during the lifetime of the request.

I have a RoleProvider and an access ActionFilter as well as a call to my repository that will all need access to this data.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't put them into the Request context?

```
HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("credentials", CredentialObject);
```

EDIT: Don't use my suggestion above. See the link in the comments for a better, testable answer.

Comment: Using HttpContext with WebApi is considered bad practice.  Its difficult to unit test and limits you to running your WebApi application on IIS only.

Comment: @JoshNoe May I ask what you would recommend to be used instead ?

Comment: @david.barkhuizen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563188/carrying-per-request-context-using-the-httprequestmessage-properties